# Oracle query with XMLEXISTS taking too much time

Tags: sql, oracle

Am trying to execute the below query and its running too long (over 20min) without giving any results. When I remove XMLEXISTS condition it fetched 41000 reccords in few seconds. What could be the issue with XMLEXISTS and how can we improve the execution time?

```
SELECT e.Entry_GUID
FROM alertdocketnext.ENTRY e inner join   
     alertdocketnext.ENTRY_PARTNERDEFINED_INFO ep
     on e.ENTRY_GUID = ep.ENTRY_GUID inner join
     alertdocketnext.PRODUCT p
     on e.PRODUCT_CODE = p.PRODUCT_CODE and p.PRODUCT_VALUE ='DocketAlertNext'
WHERE  (XMLEXISTS('/partnerDefinedInfo/facetedIds/active[text()=("active")]' PASSING PARTNERDEFINED_INFO) )
```

Comment: You probably need some sort of index on the XML data - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28369/xdb_indexing.htm

Comment: Put some plan maybe ?

Comment: Yes, index was missing. After index addition on xml field there is a huge improvement in performance. Thanks!!